# Nginx, redirection's regular expression not working properly

Tags: regex, wordpress, nginx, plesk

I've a wordpress page on a VPS with nginx and plesk. I was using this directive to remove trailing slashes from the url so everything works properly:

```
rewrite ^(.+)/+$ $1;
```

It removes trailing slashes, and I wanted, but then I couldn't access the "wp-admin" url due to too many redirects.

So I changed it to this:

```
rewrite ^(?!wp-admin)(.+)/+$ $1;
```

But it keeps removing trailing slashes from the "wp-admin" url.

Thank you all so much for your time and help.

Comment: If you're trying to discard strings having `wp-admin` then change `(?!wp-admin)` to `(?!.*wp-admin)`

Comment: Try `rewrite ^(.*)(?<!/)/+$ $1;`. Also check if another rewrite rule doesn't add a trailing `/` previously.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi that fixed it, thank you all so much for your help.